# Looked for namespace "security", found none

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am trying to create a custom bundle that is using a special authentication service. This bundle will be used by all of our projects.

I want to make it so it is needed a little configuration to use it.

My problem appears when i'm trying to add a security config inside my package like so:

```
# security.yml
security:
  providers:
    specialauth:
      id: AuthBundle\Security\SpecialAuthProvider
  firewalls:
    main:
      logout:
        path: '/logout'
```

When I do this inside my bundle I get this error:
`Looked for namespace "security", found none`

If I move this security configuration inside my app/config it works ok but I want this config to stay in the AuthBundle so the developers don't have to configure much stuff for every project.

Is this a restriction from symfony not allowing security configs from external bundles or what can the problem be?

Comment: It is not specific to security.  The Symfony configuration system is based on having a bundle provide a default configuration and then giving the app the ability to override certain settings.  I don't think you can do what you want without maybe using a compiler pass.  It would probably be best to just use the standard approach and configure at the app level.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your security.yml inside the security file of the project:

app/config/security.yml :

```
imports:
- { resource: '@AuthBundle/Resources/config/security.yml' }
```

Comment: Yes. But I am trying to move a much configuration from app level to AuthBundle level

Comment: Your application should always have a security.yml at the app level because it's linked to the application itself.

Comment: As @Cerad said I have to use some compiler passes to achieve this which we don't want to use.